# Find unique combination of identifiers in a comma-delimited list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permutation

I've got a complicated query whose results I have stored in a temporary table for the time being for simplicity's sake.  I've got a comma=delimited list of certain combinations of three character unique identifiers such as the screen cap below:

[image]

You can see in rows 2 and 3 that the 3 character identifiers are the same, but in reversed order.  The counts are different, but those values are correct (the number of people with X and Y is different than the number of people with Y and X if the population sizes of X and Y are not equal).  I would like to find the unique combinations of alldrugs, irrespective of the order in which they appear.  I envision something like a `row_number()` with a partition that gives us 1 and 2 for rows 2 and 3.

I've never attempted anything like this in SQL, but my thinking was something along the lines of

```
select *,
    case when LEN(alldrugs)-LEN(replace(alldrugs,',',''))= 1 then 2 
         when LEN(alldrugs)-LEN(REPLACE(alldrugs,',',''))= 2 then 3
         when LEN(alldrugs)-LEN(REPLACE(alldrugs,',',''))= 3 then 4
         when LEN(alldrugs)-LEN(REPLACE(alldrugs,',',''))= 4 then 5
         when LEN(alldrugs)-LEN(REPLACE(alldrugs,',',''))= 5 then 6
         else 1 end as numDrugs
    from #testfix as tf
    order by alldrugs,numDrugs
```

Since the list is comma-delimited the `case when` statement finds the number of commas in a row and gives the number of 3-digit spans to look for.  For the alldrugs columns with 2 drugs (one comma) I could make the results a CTE, self join on that CTE and check if `right(alldrugs,3) = left(alldrugs,3)`.  This obviously isn't extensible.  Is there an idiomatic way to get unique combinations like this?

Comment: Sample fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18468/1

Comment: @mellamokb thanks for that.  i'll include one of those from now on.

Comment: How many distinct drug codes do you have?

Comment: @Dems there are 7 distinct codes

Comment: Yeah, dealing with this should tell you why multi-value columns are frowned upon.  But _why_ do rows 2 and 3 have different counts?  The relationship you've listed implies an intersection, at which point they should be the same - could we get the data/query you used to generate the temp table?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse My data isn't stored in multi-valued columns.  This was just the easiest way to get a list of all combinations of drugs people took, in one, neat query.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh, show us the Real Schema. We can probably solve this in a neater way if your data is normalised already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2008+, you can use a combination of a custom `split` function and the `STUFF` function to split and recombine the lists into sorted order.  Then you can select distinct among the rearranged lists to get only unique combinations.

Here's a simple `split` function that should work ([source](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
    @RowData nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END
```

Then here is a query to grab the distinct lists:

```
select
  distinct
  STUFF((select ',' + data as [text()]
         from dbo.split(tf.alldrugs, ',')
         order by data
         FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' ) as alldrugsordered

from
  TestFix tf
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d890b/4

Sample Output:

```
| ALLDRUGSORDERED |
-------------------
|         H2F,H3A |
|             H2S |
|             H3A |
|         H3A,H4B |
|         H3A,H6H |
|             H4B |
|             H6H |
|             J7C |
```

Comment: this worked great.  I joined this table to the results that I already and viola!

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  Here is one idea, that assumes that you have a list of all possible 3 letter codes somewhere.  The idea is to expand the list, so there is one line for each row, and then to recombine the results.  In another database, you could use `group_concat` or `listagg`.  For SQL Server, we'll have to use set functions.

To expand the list:

```
with fulllist as (
    select yt.*, c.code, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as id
    from YourTable yt join
         Codes c
         on ','+yt.AllDrugs+',' like '%,'+c.code+',%'
   )
```

Next, a self-join is one way to identify when the sets are the same.  If two sets ("id"s) have the same number of drugs and all match, then they are the same.  So, for each row in the original table, we'll find the minimum row that has the same drugs.  This becomes the id for grouping purposes.

The following (untested) query implements this:

```
with fulllist as (
    select yt.*, c.code
    from YourTable yt join
         Codes c
         on ','+yt.AllDrugs+',' like '%,'+c.code+',%'
   ),
   Pairs as (
    select id1, min(id2) as minId
    from (select fl1.id as id1, fl2.id as id2
          from (select fl.*, count(*) over (partition by yt.id) as NumCodes
                from fulllist fl
               ) fl1 join
               (select fl.* count(*) over (partition by yt.id
                from fulllist fl
               ) fl2
               on fl1.code = fl2.code and
                  fl1.NumCodes = fl2.NumCodes
          group by fl1.id, fl2.id
          having count(*) as fl1.NumCodes
         ) t
     group by id1
    )
select p.minId, min(fl.AllDrugs), sum(fl.DrugFamilyCounts)
from FullList fl join
     Pairs p
     on fl.id = p.minId
group by p.minId
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: i was thinking along these lines, but my ideas weren't nearly as fleshed out.  i'll have to make a list of all possible combos and get at it.

Comment: From a comment the OP left, there are only 7 disinct drug codes. That's only 128 combinations *(including no drugs, all the way through to every drug)*. The *'combination id'* can be worked out by giving each drug code a different value from this list; `1,2,4,8,16,32,64`. Summing these values will yield a distinct result from 0 to 127 for each combination *(regardless of the order of the permutation)*. *(Assuming that each combination of drugs codes can only have 0 or 1 of each drug code.)*

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - I think you mis-understand the answer; the proposed `codes` table only needs each of the 7 drugs, not a list of the 128 combinations.

Comment: @Dems good spot, thanks.  That's an extremely interesting method you proposed and topically appears to be the most extensible.  It's holiday time for me, so I'll have to put this to rest for the moment, but that's really great insight, thanks.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't scale that well.  For 100 drugs you'd need a 100bit number to store the result in. But bit patterns work wonders in small scales.